# Porting gcc to a new target

Tags: c, gcc, compiler-construction, backend

I am trying to port gcc to a new target. The target is a new processor we designed our self with a full instruction set. We want to be able to compile c code in gcc for our new processor. To be able to accomplish that we need to port gcc for this specific target. I have read some gcc documents how to do it. So far I have edited/hacked an existing target of gcc and adopted it for our target, meaning gcc will generate assembly code for our specific processor. So I am using gcc to compile gcc for this new target. gcc will then generate a compiler myprocessor-gcc. This compiler will be able to generate assembly code for our target. by using my compiler a feed it with the following:

```
myprocessor-gcc test.c
```

test.c looks like:

```
void __main(void);


void main(void)
{
  return;
}

void __main(void)
{
int i = 0;
int i2 = 1;
int i3 = 2;
  i = i2+i3;

  return;
}
```

gcc was able to compiled this code and generated the correct assembly language I was expected.

So I elaborated my test function to:

```
void __main(void)
{
int i = 0;
int i2 = 1;
int i3 = 2;
int i4 = 3;
  i = i2+i3+i4;

  return;
}
```

After that gcc gives me a segmentation fault. I want to debug this segmentation fault, I need all the debug prints gcc can give me. So when I type:

```
myprocessor-gcc test.c -g
```

I want to see some debug prints so that I can debug gcc internally. Sorry if I am not clear, I will elaborate if this is still unclear.

Comment: Show us some code?  It's your personally designed compiler?  Can we see your CFG?

Comment: I am trying to port gcc to my 8-bit processor by means of machine descriptors, I am actually hacking a existing machine descriptor. I was able to produce some assembly code, but it is by no means completed. If I could see some debug prints it would be very helpful,  ../../configure --target=ag --prefix=location_for_my_compiler --enable-languages="c". ag is the name of my port.

Comment: I'm really curious what chip this compiler is for and what company you work for.

Comment: @DavidGrayson It is a chip me and my colleagues design as a hobby project. We are simulating the chip in Logisim. The objective is to build a full functional processor with a c compiler. It is hard to get gcc to accept the fact that the processor is only 8-bits and has only one general register (accumulator). If it is ok with my colleagues we will maybe post this project online, processor + gcc compiler. Not sure if there are many chip+compiler enthusiast out there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to make sure your cross-compiler itself was compiled with the `-g` option so it has debugging symbols in it.  Then run `gdb myprocessor-gcc test.c` to see where the segmentation fault is happening in your compiler.  You will have to learn some gdb commands like `run` and `where`.

Comment: I am running it all in cygwin should I download gdb then? How do I use -g option building the cross compiler. I am using configure..., make and then make install. None of them seems to accept the -g switch

Comment: I have no idea how to download gdb in cygwin but I am sure you can figure it out, or you could do your development in a virtual Linux machine with a distribution/package manager that you are familiar with.  The few GNU projects I have looked at enable the -g option by default so it might already be enabled, but if not then do something like `./configure --help` and look for any option related to "debug".  I just mainly wanted to point out the error in your approach, which is that you were trying to use `-g` to compile the embedded program, when in fact you actually need to debug the compiler.

Comment: The `-g` is an option that needs to be passed to gcc when you are compiling the cross-compiler; it is not an option to `make` or `configure` but there probably is a `configure` flag related to it.

Comment: I could not found any flag, but I suspected it is enable by default, I also added a macro to myprocessor.h file which is part of my gcc port. This macro is suppose to enable debugging not sure if it would work. I downloaded gdb for cygwin and found this great article that would help with debugging [debugging-gcc-with-gdb](http://muq.org/~cynbe/gcc/debugging-gcc-with-gdb-and-emacs.html)